# How does this jQuery Mobile common navigation system work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Most of the example sites (like below) that JQM link to use a common navigation system, I'll use this site as an example:

http://www.takemefishing.org/mobile/

When linking to another page that isn't already in the DOM, they use the ajax navigation for example, on the homepage they link to 'Fish Species' with a href of

`#/mobile/fish-species`.

On click, this actually loads the page into the DOM via ajax from `/mobile/fish-species` which only contains the `<div data-role="page" id="fish-species">... content here ...</div>`

Then the address bar is updated to `/mobile/#/mobile/fish-species`.

If you go directly to `/mobile/#/mobile/fish-species` (e.g. by using the refresh button or a direct link), it loads the homepage with all the CSS, JS etc etc, and then via ajax loads `/mobile/fish-species` into the DOM seemlessly.

This structure/system seems to be the common method used on JQM sites, for example [Walt Disney](http://m.disneyworld.disney.go.com/) and [Standford University](http://m.stanford.edu/).

My question is how are they making this magic happen? I suspect JQM is doing almost all of the work, and there is just some config option or flag that I am missing.

---

### Here's what I've tried

I have a basic JQM homepage `/mobile/index.html` with the `DOCTPYE`, `<head>` section with CSS, JS etc etc included, and a link to another page `page2.html`:

```
<li><a href="#/mobile/page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
```

Page 2 is similar to the 'Fish Species' page whereby it just containts the:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2.html">... content here ...</div>
```

Now, when I click the link on the homepage, page2.html is loaded into the DOM via ajax and shown. The problem is the addressbar shows:

> /mobile/page2.html

If I then click the browsers refresh button, or navigate directly to `/mobile/page2.html`, of course the browser just loads `page2.html` containing only the page `<div>` and no head section or CSS/JS included.

What am I missing to get the link to show `#/mobile/page2.html` in the address bar when loaded, and then if refreshed I want to load the homepage then pull page2 in via ajax, just like the example sites do?

I am using the latest JQM at `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Mobile will interpret navigation to the address `#address` as navigation to the `page` named `address`

This means that you can define in your single `index.html` two pages, for instance

```
<div data-role="page" id="index.html"><a href="#page2.html">link to JQM page2</a></div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2.html">... content here ...</div>
```

Clicking on the link in the first page will load the content of the second page and update the location displayed in your browser's address bar accordingly.
This is the standard JQM approach, used for instance in the stanford website you linked to.
The Disney and Fish websites look like they are doing things slightly differently as they apparently dynamically generate the target page by binding to the `pagechange` event, analyzing the target address and acting accordingly. You can see more details on dynamically generating pages in the [jquery mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html).